# How to use one CLOB output as column in another CLOB in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, clob

I am just writing small part of stored procedure, consider following as a stored procedure:

```
mainQuery CLOB := 'select name, no from main_table od ';

subQuery CLOB := 'select LISTAGG(address, '||''','''||') within group (ORDER BY address) from sub_table sb where sb.id = od.id';
```

Here, I want output of `subQuery` clob in `mainQuery` clob as a column with sub as alias name.

I very new to plsql.

Comment: Start by writing the overall query you want to get, then turn it to clob as is and replace dynamic parts with actual object names. Or use static SQL if object names and column names are static

Comment: Can you please write the query for above, it would be more helpful. Thank you so much

Comment: I cannot write query for you because I do not know what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want results of subquery clob as column in mainquery clob.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand what you are trying to achieve here, but you could try

```
    DECLARE
        mainQuery CLOB;
    BEGIN
        select 
        LISTAGG(address, '||''','''||') within group (ORDER BY address) 
        INTO mainQuery
        from sub_table sb where sb.id = od.id;
        dbms_output.put_line(mainQuery);
    END;
```